# How to get the primary key

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to get the primary key from a MS Access database. I can insert new data into it, but I cannot get the ID (primary key) from the inserted column.

```
    Name = ComboBox2.Text
    CurrentStatus = TextBox1.Text
    Login = TextBox2.Text

    pro = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\192.168.60.74\Database\Marcas\marcas.mdb"
    constring = pro

    miconexion.ConnectionString = constring
    miconexion.Open()

    comando = "insert into QATracker ([Name],[CurrentStatus],[Login],[Fecha]) values ('" & Name & "' , '" & CurrentStatus & "','" & Login & "' ,'" & Fecha & "' )"

    Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(comando, miconexion)

    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("Name", CType(Name, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("CurrentStatus", CType(CurrentStatus, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("Login", CType(Login, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("Fecha", CType(Fecha, String)))

    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        miconexion.Close()
        MsgBox("You are logged in")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        miconexion.Close()
    End Try
```

Using this code, how can I get the `ID` from the row that I just inserted?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vb.net how to get Select @@Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571605/vb-net-how-to-get-select-identity)

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454883/retrieving-identity-in-accessdb, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-identity-or-autonumber-values?redirectedfrom=MSDN#retrieving-microsoft-access-autonumber-values

Comment: While not an answer to your question, the following may be of interest: [OleDbCommand.Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0#remarks).

Comment: You may like to check [this](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?659052) out.

Comment: Why are you storing a date value (Fecha) as a String and not a date data type?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the new "just added" PK this way:

```
Protected Sub cmdAddNew_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    ' Create a new row, get ID and call pop edit
    Dim intPK As Integer

    Dim strSQL As String =
        "INSERT INTO tblHotelsA (CreateDate) VALUES (@CreateDate)"

    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.AccessDB)
        Using cmdSQL As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn)

            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@CreateDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = Date.Today
            conn.Open()
            cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()

            cmdSQL.CommandText = "SELECT @@Identity"
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Clear()

            intPK = cmdSQL.ExecuteScalar
            Debug.Print("New pk = " & intPK)

        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

As always, with Access and the OleDB provider, then order of parameters does matter, but the above shows the basic approach here.

So, "air code" warning, but your code will become much like this:

```
Dim intNewPK As Integer

Dim comando As String =
    "insert into QATracker ([Name],CurrentStatus,Login,Fecha)
    values (@Name, @CurrentStatus, @LogIn, @Fecha)"

Using conn As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.AccessDB)
    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(comando, conn)

        With cmd.Parameters
            .Add("@Name", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = ComboBox2.Text
            .Add("@CurrentStatus", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
            .Add("@LogIn", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = Teextbox2.Text
            .Add("@Fecha", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = "some undefined crap"
        End With

        conn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT @@Identity"
        cmd.Parameters.Clear()

        intNewPK = cmd.ExecuteScalar
        Debug.Print("New pk = " & intNewPK)  ' for testing - can remove

    End Using
End Using
```

More FYI:

Do keep in mind that you need to "force" the .net project to match the bit size of the version of MS-Access you have installed.

So, that means you have to force the project to x86 (x32) bits if you using Access x32, and force the project to x64 bits if using Access x64 bits.

So be aware of this setting:

[image]

Comment: there is a BIG bonus reason why I tend to use parmaeters. You don't have nor want to add quotes around the number. The rules are: Number = no quotes around the number. For string, yes then quotes, and for dates, then "#". However, in place of remembering all these rules and all that messy quotes or no quotes? Use parmaters, and then you don't have to remember, and better yet, you don't have to deal with string concatenations either. So, for numbers, you don't surround the value with quotes. But then again, if you use parameters, then you don't have to remember nor include nor use quotes anyway